# LINQ - 'The type of one of the expressions in the join clause is incorrect. Type inference failed in the call to 'GroupJoin'.'

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have this query wit a group join:

```
    foreach (var item in someList)
    {
                    var result = (from t1 in someContext.Table1
                                  join t2 in someContext.Table2 on new { t1.SomeID, item.SomeName} equals new {t2.SomeID, t2.SomeName} into j1 
                                  ...
    }
```

I would like to know if it is possible to have a group join as above?

```
new { t1.SomeID, item.SomeName} equals new {t2.SomeID, t2.SomeName}
```

`item.SomeName` comes from the list i am iterating through.

If not, how would i change the statement to get the desired results?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3020442/linq-joining-in-c-sharp-with-multiple-conditions

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The types of the properties used with the equals expression must match. So for example is `Table1.SomeID` is `Int32` and `Table2.SomeID` is `Nullable<Int32>`, then they don't match.

**EDIT**

```
foreach (var item in someList)
    {
       var someName = item.SomeName;
       var result = (from t1 in someContext.Table1
                     join t2 in someContext.Table2 on 
                               new { t1.SomeID, SomeName = someName} 
                        equals new { t2.SomeID, t2.SomeName} into j1 
                                  ...
    }
```

Also check item.SomeName is same type as t2.SomeName

Comment: They do match though, but when i change the `item.SomeName` to `t1.SomeName`, it compiles... So is that not the problem then? Can't join with a field from outside the query scope?

Comment: If one of the join key is Nullable & other is not but with same data type, can't we join them by having some conversion or anything like that?

Comment: @Jain, I think calling .GetValueOrDefault(..) will fix your problem

Answer (score 18):

In this case you must be sure that the properties and type of the two new anonymous objects are the same. I usually give specific name of properties.

Ex.:

```
 var result = from t1 in someContext.Table1
              join t2 in someContext.Table2 on 
                          new { SomeID = t1.SomeID, SomeName = someName} equals 
                          new { SomeID = t2.SomeID, SomeName = t2.SomeName} into j1
```

Comment: Giving same name to joining keys did the deed. Quite strange, types where matching though.

Comment: It seems that not only must the order and type match, but so too must the name of the field/property being compared.  If you're comparing e.g. new {x.aid, x.zid} equals new {y.aid, y.id} then you need only name either zid or id to match the other and everything will compile.  For example: new {x.aid, x.zid} equals new {y.aid, zid = y.id}

Comment: 2023 still saving people's skin.  Naming the anon types!